# Oracle Unique items not in a particular location

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

[image]

I want all item_nos not present in location 100,
THat is 1003,1005,1006,1007.

What would be the query?

WHat I was trying

```
Select distinct item_no from location where location_no not in (100)
```

But this returns 1002 as well since it has another location 200.

Comment: Can you please post your code as text, not images

Comment: edited and posted code,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having` for this:

```
select l.item_no
from location l
group by l.item_no
having sum(case when l.location = 100 then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

The `having` clause counts the number of times each item is in location 100.  The `= 0` specifies that it is never in that location.

Assuming you have an `items` table, you can also do:

```
select i.*
from items i
where not exists (select 1
                  from location l
                  where l.item_no = i.item_no and l.location = 100
                 );
```

With an index on `location(item_no, location)` this should be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use NOT IN statement to check what are the item_no that have location = 100 and select everyone besides them

```
SELECT distinct t.item_no from Location t
WHERE t.item_no NOT IN(select distinct s.item_no from Location s where s.location_no = 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct a.item_no
from location a
where not exists
(
    select 1
    from location b
    where a.item_no=b.item_no
    and b.location_no=100
)
order by a.item_no
```

Answer (score 0):

Using NOT IN may create a problem if there are item_no having NULL values.You can use MINUS also.

```
select item_no from loaction minus select item_no from location where location_no=100;
```